# Contents of child select revert to previous contents when selecting child item after calling applyBindings a second time

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to bind the contents of a child select based on the selection of a parent select.

It appears the contents of the child select are updated correctly when selecting different items from the parent list.

However when you select an item from the child select, it's contents revert to the data supplied the first time it was bound.

Why are the contents of the child list reverting?

**JsFiddle** of below http://jsfiddle.net/Xbt6k/

**HTML**

```
<div id="upper">
<select size="5" data-bind="options: optionsUpper, value: selectedOptionUpper, event:{ change: changed }"></select>
</div>
<div id="lower">
    <select data-bind="options: optionsLower, value: selectedOptionLower" size="5"></select>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var VM1 = function () {
    var self = this; 

    self.selectedOptionUpper = ko.observable();
    self.optionsUpper = ko.observableArray([1, 2]);

    self.changed = function () {
        var s = self.selectedOptionUpper();

        var data;

        if (s == 1) {
            data = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
        } else if (s == 2) {
            data = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
        }

        ko.applyBindings(new VM2(data), document.getElementById('lower'));
    };
};

var VM2 = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.selectedOptionLower = ko.observable();
    self.optionsLower = ko.observableArray(data);
};

ko.applyBindings(new VM1(), document.getElementById('upper'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think knockout is getting confused between the bindings in both select's along with the re-applying of bindings every time the top one changes.

Here's a more "knockout" way of doing things.  This example has a simple view model that contains an array of items.  Each item contains the data to display in the upper select along with an array of items to show in the lower select:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.selectedOptionUpper = ko.observable();
    self.selectedOptionLower = ko.observable();
    self.optionsUpper = [
        { data: 1, items: [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ]},
        { data: 2, items: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]}
        ];
    self.showData = function() {
        alert('upper: ' + self.selectedOptionUpper().data + ', lower: ' + self.selectedOptionLower());
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Next, the HTML binding.  Note the lower select is bound to the "items" collection of whatever is selected in the upper select (with a null check for the initial page load when nothing is selected):

```
<div id="upper">
    <select size="5" data-bind="options: optionsUpper, optionsText: 'data', value: selectedOptionUpper"></select>
</div>
<div id="lower">
    <select data-bind="options: selectedOptionUpper() ? selectedOptionUpper().items : [], value: selectedOptionLower" size="5"></select>
</div>
<input type="button" data-bind="click: showData" value="Show" />
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psteele/Abrb4/).